# Google SketchUp and 3D with C#

Tags: c#, 3d, sketchup

I'm not familiar at all with working with 3D, but I need to make a C# application that uses 3D object (just to view them). I think that it would be easiest to make 3D model in Google SketchUp. But I don't how to use .skp files in C#. And could also someone recommend me some resources how to use C# to manipulate with 3D objects.

Answer (score 1):

You might be lucky:

http://www.3drad.com/Google-SketchUp-To-DirectX-XNA-Exporter-Plug-in.htm

However, that will lead you to more trouble with Microsoft XNA, and then you'll probably investigate other 3D rendering methods, and that might lead you to

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/MOGRE

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of stuff you can or may want to do. So the question is vague enough. 
Just to give a hints.

You should look if you want to look into [Vector Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) 3D models, like for example [IGES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGES) which used in `CAD`  mechanical manufacturing, or you can look on models created from the mash, like for example [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) files, mainly used in scanners as recover a cloud of points a construct from it a sequence of triangles.

There are also a plenty other solutions and types.

Just a couple of **coding** useful links you may be interested in:

- [XNA Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197293%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)
- [OpenCascade](http://www.opencascade.org/)(you can find a `C#` wrappers in internet. Original project is in `C++` obviously.

And another couple of **applications** you may be interested to look at:

- [Rhino](http://www.it.rhino3d.com/). Great 3D modeling program, with free version, that is limited on count of saves you may execute (arround 20) Excelent for working with vectorial and mashes.
- [FreeCAD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/free-cad/). Good for mechanical manufacturing and it's free.
- [Magics](http://www.materialise.com/Magics). Good for working with STL files. There is a free version too.

Answer (score 0):

I may be heading you in a wrong direction but as far as I know Microsoft Expression Blend handles WPF and 3d objects. Hope that was helpful to you.